# How can you use string instead of == or != in IF statement

Tags: php, if-statement, eval

I wonder how i can make if work if i put `==` or `!=` in variable e.g.

```
$comparison_operator = " != ";

if ( 5 $comparison_operator 5 ) {
   echo "true";
} else {
   echo "false";
}
```

i tried with `eval()` however only works when you put entire expression in it not just variable.

This works

```
$comparison_operator = " != ";

if ( eval('return(5 $comparison_operator 5);') ) {
   echo "true";
} else {
   echo "false";
}
```

This does not and i need version that looks like this to work somehow, i tried **variable variables** without luck as well, any ideas?

```
$comparison_operator = " != ";

if ( 5 eval('return($comparison_operator)') 5 ) {
   echo "true";
} else {
   echo "false";
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: interesting, never thought about this..

Comment: I don't think PHP will allow you to use a variable for the operand.  Try an if-else statement to determine which operand to use.

Comment: I agree with @PeeHaa

Comment: The second eval attempt will never work because eval returns an expression, not an operand: i.e., its returning the string `" != "` as a string.

Comment: Why variable variable does not work too?

Its a lesson i got in my college to find out why it dont work.

Comment: `$comparison_operator = " != ";

function compare($operand1, $operand2, $operator) {
    switch ($operator) {
        case '==' :
            return $operand1 == $operand2;
        case '!=' :
            return $operand1 != $operand2;
    }
}

if (compare(5, $comparison_operator, 5)) {
   echo "true";
} else {
   echo "false";
}`

Comment: Variable variable allows you to use a variable as a variable name...not to use a variable as an operator.

Comment: @RomanToasov you got some advance?

Comment: Your first attempt is correct but 2nd one wrong code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$comparison_operator = " == ";
eval("\$op = 5" . $comparison_operator . "5 ? true : false;");

if ($op) {
   echo "true";
} else {
   echo "false";
}

?>
```